# Jasmine jQuery loop unit test

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

How to write a Jasmine unit test for a jQuery *for* loop? For example if this has to be tested:

```
$(".class").each(function(index))
{ 
  testFunction()
}
```

the HTML structure is a list of divs with each div having *class* as a class.

Comment: So what exactly do you wish to test?

Comment: Want to test the function inside the loop is being called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to utilize Jasmine [spies](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-Spies) to track the calls to function as follows

```
function testFunction() {
  alert("asd");
}

function foo() {
  $(".class").each(
    function(index) {
      testFunction()
    }
  )
}

describe("foo()", function () {
  var wrapper;
  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(window, 'testFunction');
  });

  it("calls testFunction for each element", function () {
    foo(); 
    expect(window.testFunction.calls.count()).toEqual(jQuery(".class").length);
  })
});
```

I wrote a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvc0p3hw/) for you that you can play with.

The main point is the *spyOn* call that stubs the *window* object's *testFunction*. That makes it possible to override every call on the testFunction and react on it any way we wish. On this case we simply let it be executed and take the call count after it with *calls.count()* and compare it to the amount of elements with class *class*.